# Событие turbolinks:load не работает

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблемы.

Я использую rails5 с гемом turbolinks. Вот код меню моего сайта:

```
<div id="templatemo_menu" class="ddsmoothmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="level_0 index" href="/">Главная</a></li>

      <li><a class="level_0 about" href="/pages/about">О нас</a></li>

      <li><a class="level_0 portfolio" href="/type_works">Портфолио</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=1">Corporate Metrics Liaison</a></li>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=2">Chief Solutions Planner</a></li>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=3">Central Applications Architect</a></li>
            <li><a class="level_1" href="/works?type_work_id=4">Global Metrics Executive</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li><a class="level_0 blog" href="/blog_articles">Блог</a></li>

      <li><a class="level_0 contact" href="/contact_messages/new">Контакт</a></li>
    </ul>

    <br style="clear: left">
  </div>
```

Я хотел бы чтобы после клика по пункту "О нас" цвет фона BODY поменялся на красный. Причём всё это происходило бы на основе разбора адресной строки. Вот моя попытка решения:

```
var menuActivePunkt = function(){ 
  var pathname = location.pathname,
    pathnameList = pathname.split('/'),
    slug1 = pathnameList[1],
    slug2 = pathnameList[2];

  console.log('slug1', slug1);
  console.log('slug2', slug2);

  $('#templatemo_menu a').removeClass('selected').on('click', function() {
    if(slug1 == 'pages' && slug2 == 'about') {
      //$('.index').addClass('selected');
      $('body').css({'background': 'red'});
    };
  });
}


$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  menuActivePunkt();
})
```

Проблема в том, что после того как я кликаю по пункту "О нас", цвет фона BODY на долю секунды меняется на красный, но затем вновь становится белым. Я этого не понимаю, мне нужно чтобы он остался красным. Помогите пожалуйста это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#templatemo_menu a').removeClass('selected').on('click', function() {
    if(slug1 == 'pages' && slug2 == 'about') {
      //$('.index').addClass('selected');
      $('body').css({'background': 'red'});
    };
  });
```

меняем на

```
if(slug1 == 'pages' && slug2 == 'about') {
  //$('.index').addClass('selected');
  $('body').css({'background': 'red'});
}
```

а с классами `<a>` работаем отдельно

Comment: Вы знаете, что такое Turbolinks и почему от него здесь проблемы? :)

Comment: Видимо, чел имел в виду то, что нужно этот кусок встроить не в head, а в body. Тем самым заставляя при каждой смене страницы отрабатывать скрипт заново. Но это не работает. Проблема осталась та же

Comment: Я разобраля, turbolinks не при чём тут был. Денис прав - ".on('click'," нужно было удалить совсем